# insert some values into file with awk and sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Let's imagine there is some file.txt with such data:

```
@@comp1,1111,1111,pass
@@comp2,2222,2222,pass
.
.
@@comp34,error,,,fail
.
.
@@comp65,6565,6565,pass
```

Then I have to insert missed values, here they are:

```
expected=3434,observed=0000
```

in proper fields before "fail". Also I have `$line_number` where it should be inserted:

```
 @@comp34,error,3434,0000,fail
```

I tried different solutions but they don't work. 
e.g.:

```
new1=`awk -n=$line_number -F, '{print $3}' text.txt` | sed 's/$new1/$expected' > text.txt
new2=`awk -n=$line_number -F, '{print $4}' text.txt` | sed 's/$new2/$observed' > text.txt
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk -F, -vln="$line" -vexpe="$expected" -vobs="$observed" 'NR==ln{$3=expe;$4=obs}1' OFS=, file
```

Output will be:

```
@@comp1,1111,1111,pass
@@comp2,2222,2222,pass
.
.
@@comp34,error,3434,0000,fail
.
.
@@comp65,6565,6565,pass
```

Comment: is there is any possibility to rewrite existent file with new changes after inserting that values?

Comment: Or `awk -i inplace '...' orig_file` with GNU awk 4.*. Not leaving a space between `-v` and `var=...` already makes the script GNU awk specific anyway.